# how to set the DropDownButton automatically dropdown when I move from one selected DropDownButton to another one DropDownButton in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have tried to create few DropDownButtons inside a statusStrip in C# windown form.
It's normal that when I just move the cursor to the button, it will not drop down the items, it only drop down the items only when I clicked the DropDownButton.

However the issue is after I clicked on `DropDownButton1`, it drops down the items, but when I move the cursor to another `DropDownButton2`, the items of `DropDownButton2` will not drop down!!
How can I set the items of `DropDownButton2` automatically drop down when I move mouse after clicking `DropDownButton1`? Just like the general application?

Thanks all!

Comment: Can we see some code, please?

Comment: Please add a minimal example see :http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sorry, I didn't try any code for it, I just use the Design view to create & add the DropDownButton & items..

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [ComboBox.DroppedDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.droppeddown.aspx) property,
set it to true on [MouseHover](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover(v=vs.110).aspx) event

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
this.dropDown1.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.dropDown1_MouseHover);



private void dropDown1_MouseHover(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
    //Set the dropdown1 to dropped
    dropDown1.DroppedDown = true; 

    //Set the other dropdown to undropped
    dropDown2.DroppedDown = false;

}
```

For more info add more code!